# Words to describe database users

Tags: single-word-requests

This is a multi-faceted question (if that's allowed). I am running a web application with a database that is used by Westerners and Asians, so cultural sensitivity is important. I am implementing some "fun" statistics. They will be used in the following manner: `Today's <word> is <username>`. Where the `<word>` placeholder is replaced by a word describing one of three things:

1. The most active user, based on number of page views.
2. A user that logs in exactly once, then has no other records in the log file (i.e. they log in, but then don't do anything else).
3. A user that has been absent for a long time, then logs in unexpectedly.

These words are similar to the [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) gained on the Stack Exchange network, but I prefer singular words, if possible. I would also prefer words that are non-religious (or faith neutral) and not related to death (especially in relation to the third point).

The best my brain can come up with is:

1. busybody
2. sloth
3. resurrectee

But I'm not happy with those; hence this question.

Comment: What’s a singular adjective? None of your examples are adjectives; those are all nouns. Calling somebody a busybody user or a sloth user doesn’t sound very sensitive to me.

Comment: My apologies, I thought an adjective was a 'describing word'?

Comment: A word that describes a person **can** be an adjective, as in *young* or *happy*, but words like *boy*, *busybody*, *fireman*, and *police* are all nouns even though they’re describing people. One easy test that often works is whether you can add *-er* and *-est* to inflect an adjective into the comparative and superlative degrees, as in *younger* or *happiest*. You can’t do that with nouns. Another test is to try to apply *very* to it: you can’t really say "very boy", but you can and do commonly say "very young". Nouns can be singular or plural in English, but adjectives cannot.

Comment: @tchrist I have updated my question

Comment: You still have "adjectives" in the title

Comment: I'm sorry to say I see no faint justification for posting that here.

How is anything you asked anything but a mater of opinion, please?

Comment: Busy bee; Lazy bones; Out of the blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've gone with:

1. Clickaholic
2. Sleeper
3. Guest

Answer (score 0):

Not all single words but good fits, I think:

1. Overachiever (someone who does more than expected)
2. [Bump-on-a-log](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/like-a-bump-on-a-log)  (someone that is inert, unmoving, inactive)
3. surprise guest

Comment: Good suggestions! Keep 'em coming!